# Is there any way I can know creation date of an Index for MongoDB tables(collections)?

Tags: mongodb, date, indexing, collections, creation

Is there any way I can know creation date of an Index  for MongoDB tables(collections)? Recently, we saw some indexes which lead to some problem of space and performance and wonder if we can get the timestamp for create_date of the indexes. And I'm not sure if there is a way to do that in the most recent version of mongodb. and if not so, is there any workaround to do that? Thanks a  lot.

Comment: Hey tony.. did u find the answer since its been around 4 years....:) ?  i have same question..

Answer (score 2):

db.t1.aggregate( [ { $indexStats: { } } ] ) , check since

Answer (score 1):

Check the `rs.oplog` collection in the `local` database.

```
db.oplog.rs.find({ "o.createIndexes": { "$exists": true } }).sort({ts: -1})
```

A sample response: (when an index with name `unique_email` was created on `users` collection in `test` database.

```
{ op: 'c',
  ns: 'test.$cmd',
  ui: UUID("47041281-c7d2-4d28-90ef-2baa49c6c31f"),
  o: 
   { createIndexes: 'users',
     v: 2,
     unique: true,
     key: { email: 1 },
     name: 'unique_email',
     background: false },
  ts: Timestamp({ t: 1659682522, i: 2 }),
  t: 62,
  v: 2,
  wall: 2022-08-05T06:55:22.326Z }
```

### CAVEATS

`oplog` retention is limited both in terms of size of the `oplog` collection and how long ago the operation was performed. You can read more about these parameters in the [official documentation](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/replica-set-oplog/).
All write operations are recorded in the `oplog`, including index creation, but you are more likely to find the `oplog` entry if the index was created recently.
Therefore, **this method will only work in some cases.**